# Rounded corners do not transform well in Tikz under a nonlinear transformation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, transformation

I want to apply a nonlinear transformation to the following image

[image]

Whose code is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,-2) grid [step=1] (4,2);
\draw[
fill=green!30, draw=blue, very thick, rounded corners=5ex, opacity=.5, dashed] (-2.,-1.) rectangle (2.,1.);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

With the nonlinear transformation I found [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426701/nonlinear-transformation-of-tikzpicture-according-to-a-function) I get
[image]

The code is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}

\makeatletter
\def\mytransformation{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgf@x + 4*sin(4*\pgf@y) }
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{\pgf@y}
\setlength{\pgf@x}{\myX pt}
\setlength{\pgf@y}{\myY pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}%Inside the scope transformation is active
\pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}

\draw (-4,-2) grid [step=1] (4,2);

\draw[
fill=green!30, draw=blue, very thick, rounded corners=5ex, opacity=.5, dashed] (-2.,-1.) rectangle (2.,1.);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How is it possible to let the edges transform well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rounded corners`command does not seem to work in this case (see here about it [Nonlinear transformation applied on decorations along path with a custom pic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645110/nonlinear-transformation-applied-on-decorations-along-path-with-a-custom-pic/645224#645224)).  I propose this way to solve this problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}

\makeatletter
\def\mytransformation{%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgf@x + 4*sin(4*\pgf@y) }
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{\pgf@y}
\setlength{\pgf@x}{\myX pt}
\setlength{\pgf@y}{\myY pt}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\xx{1}
\pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}
\draw (-5,-5) grid [step=1] (5,5);
\draw[fill=green!30, draw=blue, very thick,opacity=.5, dashed]
(-2,-1+\xx) -- (-2,1-\xx).. controls (-2,1) ..
(-2+\xx,1) -- (2-\xx,1).. controls (2,1) ..
(2,1-\xx) -- (2,-1+\xx).. controls (2,-1) ..
(2-\xx,-1) -- (-2+\xx,-1).. controls (-2,-1) ..
(-2,-1+\xx);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can play with the `\xx` parameter within certain limits.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the object is to be defined manually, very nice solution!. It seems you've been working with my old code on this post. Thanks

Comment: So do you mean with \xx a number one must choose or is it a part of the code, a variable for example ?

Comment: @Physor  Thank you. If the rectangle has dimensions a x b and a<b, then parameter xx can be chosen in the range 0<=xx<= a/2, either as described in my code `\newcommand\xx{1}` or like this `\def\xx{0.8}` In addition you can change control points or add new ones if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The option `rounded corners` is quite stubborn sometimes: it has several pitfalls. For instance it does not work well with `scale`, see [pgfmanual.pdf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), *Section 14.5
Rounding Corners*.

To avoid using this option, one simple way is define your own round rectangle path

```
\def\myround{.4}        % radius of the rounding corners    
\def\myrectangle{(0,2)
    --(3-\myround,2)   arc(90:0:\myround)
    --(3,-2+\myround)  arc(0:-90:\myround)
    --(-3+\myround,-2) arc(-90:-180:\myround)
    --(-3,2-\myround)  arc(180:90:\myround)--cycle;
}
```

Hence, with your `\pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}`

[image]

and without `\pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}`

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\makeatletter
\def\mytransformation{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myX}{\pgf@x + 4*sin(4*\pgf@y) }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myY}{\pgf@y}
    \setlength{\pgf@x}{\myX pt}
    \setlength{\pgf@y}{\myY pt}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myround{.4}        % radius of the rounding corners    
\def\myrectangle{(0,2)
    --(3-\myround,2)   arc(90:0:\myround)
    --(3,-2+\myround)  arc(0:-90:\myround)
    --(-3+\myround,-2) arc(-90:-180:\myround)
    --(-3,2-\myround)  arc(180:90:\myround)--cycle;
}   
\begin{scope} % Inside the scope, the transformation is active
\pgftransformnonlinear{\mytransformation}
\draw[gray!30] (-5,-3) grid (5,3);
\draw[blue,fill=green!30,very thick,fill opacity=.5,dashed] \myrectangle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The other solution is also similar, but it seems better to use ```control```s than ```acr```s. Because the edges didn't stick to the grid as in the other answer.